# laravel 5.2 store data in session after authentication

Tags: laravel-5

I'm usin laravel 5.2, I would like to know how to store or save data into session variable when a user is successfully authenticated. I'm using default authentication of laravel.

Comment: Which value you want to store? What have you tried?

Comment: @ Abhishek: I want to store some data how: RoleId, Role Name, Menu Options by rol, User FirstName and LastName that is in another table..

Answer (score -1):

What you are asking is too broad. Though considering you only want to know how to store data in session then :

```
session()->put('key', 'value');
```

And to retrieve data then :

```
session()->get('key');
```

Also, now if you want to store a logged in users role id in to session and the users to roles table has one to one relationship then you can do something like :

```
session()->put('role_id', auth()->user()->role()->id);
```

Comment: where should i put that code? I'm using default authentication of laravel. I should to put into some part of AuthController?. You could show me an example please?